# Repeating a value within each ID when there are multiple value options in R

Tags: r, multi-level

I have a dataset in R with multiple height observations within different IDs. For some IDs, there are several different height measures and for some, there is only one. For most observations/rows within each ID, the height value is missing (coded as NA).  I want to create a new variable which takes the first height measure available per ID and repeats it for all rows/observations of that ID (different IDs have different numbers of rows total). I have tried working with fill, mutate and with commands but I am struggling to make it work.

Currently my data looks like this:

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 height = c(150, NA, NA, NA, 148, NA, 152, 151, NA))

# id height
# 1  1    150
# 2  1     NA
# 3  1     NA
# 4  2     NA
# 5  2    148
# 6  3     NA
# 7  3    152
# 8  3    151
# 9  3     NA
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to add a variable (height_filled) so it will look like this:

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  height = c(150, NA, NA, NA, 148, NA, 152, 151, NA),
                  height_filled = c(150, 150, 150, 148, 148, 152, 152, 152, 152))

# id height height_filled
# 1  1    150           150
# 2  1     NA           150
# 3  1     NA           150
# 4  2     NA           148
# 5  2    148           148
# 6  3     NA           152
# 7  3    152           152
# 8  3    151           152
# 9  3     NA           152
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` option using `first` + `na.omit`

```
setDT(data)[, height_filled := first(na.omit(height)), id]
```

gives

```
   id height height_filled
1:  1    150           150
2:  1     NA           150
3:  1     NA           150
4:  2     NA           148
5:  2    148           148
6:  3     NA           152
7:  3    152           152
8:  3    151           152
9:  3     NA           152
```

---

A base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  data,
  height_filled = ave(height, id, FUN = function(x) head(na.omit(x), 1))
)
```

gives

```
  id height height_filled
1  1    150           150
2  1     NA           150
3  1     NA           150
4  2     NA           148
5  2    148           148
6  3     NA           152
7  3    152           152
8  3    151           152
9  3     NA           152
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all these answers - they all did what I wanted them to. The final use of setDT helped me add this variable to my existing data set which was great. Very grateful for all the thoughts!

Answer (score 4):

I would try the following. After grouping by `id`, use `na.omit` for `height` to remove missing values, and use `first` to select the first height available after `NA` removal.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(height_filled = first(na.omit(height)))
```

**Output**

```
     id height height_filled
  <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1    150           150
2     1     NA           150
3     1     NA           150
4     2     NA           148
5     2    148           148
6     3     NA           152
7     3    152           152
8     3    151           152
9     3     NA           152
```

Answer (score 2):

Either we can group by 'id', `arrange` the 'id' and the NA in 'height' and use `cummax`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(id, is.na(height)) %>% 
   mutate(height_filled = cummax(replace(height, is.na(height), 0))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     id height height_filled
#  <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#1     1    150           150
#2     1     NA           150
#3     1     NA           150
#4     2    148           148
#5     2     NA           148
#6     3    152           152
#7     3    151           152
#8     3     NA           152
#9     3     NA           152
```

---

Or use `max` on the 'height' grouped by 'id'

```
data %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(height_filled = max(height, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     id height height_filled
#  <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#1     1    150           150
#2     1     NA           150
#3     1     NA           150
#4     2     NA           148
#5     2    148           148
#6     3     NA           152
#7     3    152           152
#8     3    151           152
#9     3     NA           152
```